# How can I change the url in Flutter web?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I need to change the content of this web page

[image]

for this content
[image]

And also change the url from "localhost:49318/#/home/inicio" to "localhost:49318/#/home/other".

All of this without using the Navigator.

In a mobile app I would change the widget shown with a set state, but doing that on a web page wouldn't change the url.

Answer (score 21):

I use Fluro (a package) to control my routes, but eventually I need to change the URL without redirecting.

The solution is pretty simple

Import this:

```
import 'dart:html' as html;
```

Then in your code, use this to change the URL without affecting the current page

```
html.window.history.pushState(null, 'home', '#/home/other');
```

Comment: Thanks for letting us know about this package. It looks really awesome and I am going to use it in my own project.

Comment: On pressing the back button it is not going to the last screen, for that we're required to press the browser's back button twice

Answer (score 0):

The url in browser won't change unless you navigate it to specific one.
Yes, `setState((){})` will work in mobile(here too) but it will change/replace the widget to the new one it won't navigate to your target.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Flutter Navigator 2.0 you can use a `RouteNavigationParser` which handles URL parsing for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the url to a html page, you can just use:

Import

```dart
import 'dart:html' as html;
// or even better: import 'package:universal_html/html.dart' as html;
```

```dart
final myPath = 'payment.html';
html.window.location.href = myPath;
```

(considering your file located at web/payment.html)